# Swap last two elements of a list in Prolog

Tags: list, prolog

I've been  trying to write a program that compares two lists hat are the same except the last two elements of List 2  are in reverse order, i.e [4,5,6] and [4,6,5], and that returns the last two elements that have been swapped.

For example:

```
SwapLastTwo([4, 5, 6] , [ 4, 6, 5], X).
```

should return

```
X = [6, 5]
```

So far my  code looks like this:

```
lastTwoReversed([Z,A|T],[_,Y,X]) :-reverse([Z,A|T],[Y,X|_]).
```

My predicate so far only takes two arguments and checks, if are the same except the last two elements of List 2  are in reverse order and returns `true`, if the condsitions are met

I don't know how I can modify my predicate to  incoparate the `X` as its third argument and make it return the swapped elements.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
lastTwoReversed(L1, L2, [X1,X2]) :-
    reverse(L1, [X1,X2|Rest]),
    reverse(L2, [X2,X1|Rest]).
```

Notice that by using the variable `Rest` in both subgoals, you establish that the lists must be the same, except for the last two items (which are *swapped*).

Example:

```
?- lastTwoReversed([1,2,3,4,5,6], [1,2,3,4,6,5], R).
R = [6, 5].

?- lastTwoReversed([1,2,3,4,5,6], [1,2,3,6,5], R).
false.

?- lastTwoReversed([1,2,3,4,5,6], [1,2,3,4,5,6], R).
false.
```

Comment: Maybe it's all about being the dominant elite... lol https://dev.to/facundocorradini/why-i-don-t-use-stack-overflow-1f0l

Comment: Just to put it into context, my comment above was the answer to a user who asked me why someone downvote a good solution (after my solution was downvoted). The question asked has been deleted.

Answer (score 3):

Using first-argument indexing, and improved performance by removing the unnecessary reverse(), and also same_length():

```
swap_last_2([Elem1, Elem2|Tail], SwappedLst, Last2) :-
    % same_length would prevent an unwanted choicepoint on: swap_last_2(L, [a,b], SL).
    %same_length([Elem1, Elem2|Tail], SwappedLst),
    swap_last_2_(Tail, Elem1, Elem2, SwappedLst, Last2).


% Swap the last 2 elements
swap_last_2_([], Elem1, Elem2, [Elem2, Elem1], [Elem2, Elem1]).

swap_last_2_([Head|Tail], Elem1, Elem2, [Elem1|SwappedLst], Last2) :-
    % Move the elements along
    swap_last_2_(Tail, Elem2, Head, SwappedLst, Last2).
```

Result in swi-prolog:

```
?- swap_last_2([4, 5, 6], [4, 6, 5], X).
X = [6,5].
```

Performance comparison (this method is fastest):

```
?- cmp(1000, 1000).
% 7,011,001 inferences, 0.503 CPU in 0.497 seconds (101% CPU, 13941510 Lips)
% 2,001,001 inferences, 0.282 CPU in 0.278 seconds (101% CPU, 7098617 Lips)
% 2,007,001 inferences, 0.205 CPU in 0.203 seconds (101% CPU, 9782721 Lips)
% 1,002,001 inferences, 0.063 CPU in 0.063 seconds (101% CPU, 15819840 Lips)
```

Comment: I've upvoted you answer, but I think the call to `same_length/2` is not really necessary: if `swap_last_2_/2` ends up with the first list empty and the second one with exactly two items, it means that the lists given as input to `swap_last_2/2` indeed have the same length. By eliminating this call, you will have an even faster code [yet it will still have time complexity O(*n*) ].

Comment: @slago Yes, I've commented out same_length/2, for still more performance. In the version from yesterday, it was needed to prevent an infinite loop, but instead now merely prevents an unwanted choicepoint.

Answer (score 0):

I think the comparison made by @CapelliC [that has been deleted] is misleading. The OP asks for a predicate to **compare two lists** and check if they are the same, except for the last two elements that may appear swapped (*which is different from a predicate that **just** swaps the last two elements of a single list*). Thus, a fairer comparison should call the predicates to be compared with **two instantiated lists as input**.

My suggestion is to modify `perf_belt/3` as follows:

```
/*  File:    last2swap_perf.pl
    Author:  Carlo
    Created: Dec 12 2021
    Purpose: compare answers to https://stackoverflow.com/q/70281408/874024
*/

:- module(last2swap_perf, [cmp/2]).

:- meta_predicate perf_belt(+,+,3).

% CapelliC's solutions

% append/2 based

last2swap_app2(A,B,[U,V]):-
    append([C,[U,V]],A),
    append([C,[V,U]],B).

% append/3 based

last2swap_app3(A,B,[U,V]):-
    append(C,[U,V],A),
    append(C,[V,U],B).

% slago' solution

lastTwoReversed(L1, L2, [X1,X2]) :-
    reverse(L1, [X1,X2|Rest]),
    reverse(L2, [X2,X1|Rest]).

% brebs' answer

swap_last_2([Elem1, Elem2|Tail], SwappedLst, Last2) :-
    swap_last_2_(Tail, Elem1, Elem2, [], RevSwappedLst, Last2),
    reverse(RevSwappedLst, SwappedLst).

% This swaps the last 2 elements

swap_last_2_([], Elem1, Elem2, SoFar, [Elem1, Elem2|SoFar], [Elem2, Elem1]).

swap_last_2_([Head|Tail], Elem1, Elem2, SoFar, SwappedLst, Last2) :-
    % Move the elements along
    swap_last_2_(Tail, Elem2, Head, [Elem1|SoFar], SwappedLst, Last2).

%!  %%% minimal perf utility

perf_belt(NRep, LList, Pred) :-       % <== NEW VERSION PROPOSED
    make_lists(LList, List1, List2), 
    time( forall(between(1, NRep, _), % <== TWO INSTANTIATED LISTS AS INPUT 
                 call(Pred, List1, List2, _)) ).

make_lists(N, List1, List2) :-
    N1 is N - 1,
    N2 is N - 2,
    numlist(1, N2, Prefix),
    append(Prefix, [N1, N], List1),
    append(Prefix, [N, N1], List2).

cmp(NRep,LList) :-
    perf_belt(NRep,LList,last2swap_app2),
    perf_belt(NRep,LList,last2swap_app3),
    perf_belt(NRep,LList,lastTwoReversed),
    perf_belt(NRep,LList,swap_last_2).
```

**Fairer results** Running on SWI-Prolog, version 8.4.1, we can see that double reverse is not so bad.

```
?- cmp(100, 100).
% 71,101 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (?% CPU, Infinite Lips)
% 20,101 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (?% CPU, Infinite Lips)
% 20,701 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (?% CPU, Infinite Lips)
% 20,401 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (?% CPU, Infinite Lips)
true.

?- cmp(100, 1000).
% 701,101 inferences, 0.047 CPU in 0.047 seconds (100% CPU, 14956821 Lips)
% 200,101 inferences, 0.031 CPU in 0.031 seconds (100% CPU, 6403232 Lips)
% 200,701 inferences, 0.016 CPU in 0.016 seconds (100% CPU, 12844864 Lips)
% 200,401 inferences, 0.016 CPU in 0.016 seconds (100% CPU, 12825664 Lips)
true.

?- cmp(1000, 1000).
% 7,011,001 inferences, 0.438 CPU in 0.437 seconds (100% CPU, 16025145 Lips)
% 2,001,001 inferences, 0.219 CPU in 0.219 seconds (100% CPU, 9147433 Lips)
% 2,007,001 inferences, 0.141 CPU in 0.141 seconds (100% CPU, 14272007 Lips)
% 2,004,001 inferences, 0.141 CPU in 0.141 seconds (100% CPU, 14250674 Lips)
true.
```

Comment: You're true, my fault using uninstantiated argument subject to backtracking. Sorry for the noise.

Comment: @CapelliC No problem! Indeed I must thank you! Your answer helped clarify the matter, as my answer has been criticized by those who think it is too inefficient.

Comment: I have improved my code by removing its one reverse(), so it is now significantly faster.

Comment: @brebs Nice! Each call to `reverse/2` (complete list traversing) has time complexity O(*n*). So, by eliminating one such call (and traversing both lists in parallel, as you have done) this efficiency gain was actually expected. Note, however, that the temporal complexities of the algorithms remains the same, O(*n*). The advantage of this new version is due only to a constant factor (that seems to be less than 2).